# Exercise about category theory

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}: Sets \to Sets$ a representable functor and $f:S \to T$ an onto function. Then $\mathcal{F}(f):\mathcal{F}(S) \to \mathcal{F}(T)$ is onto.

By definition, $\exists A \in Sets $ s.t. $\eta: \mathcal{H}_A \to \mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism. Then we have $ \mathcal{F}(f) \circ \eta_S (\phi) = \eta_T \circ \mathcal{H}_A (f) (\phi)$ where $\phi \in \mathcal{H}_A(S)$. Also we have that $\eta_X$ is a bijection.

I don't know what to do. The proof would finish if we can check that every element in $\mathcal{F}(T)$ can be express by $\eta_T \circ \mathcal{H}_A (f) (\phi)$.

Comment: You need to show that $\mathcal{H}_A\left(f\right)$ is onto. This is easy.

Comment: Note: There is a simpler proof, which does not use the representability of $\mathcal{F}$. Just notice that $f$ has a right inverse $g$, and so $\mathcal{F}\left(f\right)$ has $\mathcal{F}\left(g\right)$ as its right inverse. Both of these proofs use the axiom of choice, but I guess it is unavoidable here (and an appropriate easy modification is constructive).

Comment: I can't see how the hypothesis that $F$ is representable helps you at all here. Abstract nonsense tells you that any functor preserving limits (including any representable functor) preserves monomorphisms, but not necessarily epimorphisms. And as darij says, epimorphisms in $\text{Set}$ split (this is a form of the axiom of choice), and any functor whatsoever preserves split epimorphisms.